# Font Substitution, didn't show correct characters on Bold or Italic

Tags: windows, fonts

I have an old software which use 'MS Sans Serif' font to display text.
While we add some unicode content, this font can't show some of them correctly.
I used font substitution in windows registry to use Tahoma instead of Ms Sans serif. it work correctly in many cases, but some labels which show Bold or italic content, after my register changes, are un-readable now. and show characters in another Codepage ( maybe )

How is it possible to define font substitution on Bold or Italic text decoration?

Edit : I add a value for MS Sans Serif,0 in Font Substitution, and this fix my problem.